# Select specific rows in attributes table by using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

With the zonal statistics as table I made a "park_dem.dbf" file which shows in 28 rows the name of  polygon and also several information about the (max-min-range-area) so my question is,  how can I select the four named specific rows (which I know the name) among the all names in the table and then find that which of these four area has the max range? So after that I have to export this selected area to the shapefile.

So this is my script which I have done. Is there anyone who can help me to solve this?

(I am not a beginner in Python)

```
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = 'ArcCR500_v32/'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
try:
    if arcpy.CheckExtension('Spatial')=='Available':
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension('Spatial')
    else:
        raise LicenseError
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage('Spatial Analyst License is not available')

#make mix table
in_zone_data = 'ArcCR500_v32/ChranenaUzemi.shp'
zone_field = 'NAZEV_ASCI'
in_value_raster = 'ArcCR500_v32/dem'
out_table = 'Park_dem.dbf'

result_table = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(in_zone_data,zone_field,in_value_raster,out_table, 'DATA')
```

Comment: Have you looked into [search cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/searchcursor-class.htm)? With a `where_clause`, you can select those particular 4 rows.

Comment: It depends on what you want to *do* with the rows.. as @Paul said a search/update cursor with a where clause (name in ('value1','value2','value3','value4')) would work but you could also make a table view with the same where clause or if you already have one a tool like Table Select can export the rows to a new table. If you could explain a bit more on what you're trying to do with the rows perhaps we could make a more specific suggestion.

Comment: Do you need to solve that using ArcPy? I'd go for Excel (which can open DBFs) as the maximum selection is much easier there.

Comment: i have selected my specific area form the list(Name and maximum Range) by using "arcpy.da.SearchCursor" but now i have to create a new shape file with my new selected area, so can you please help me how can i make a shape file with my data.